# how to access data to DAO to Contoller to UI in angular js ng-grid

Tags: java, spring, angular

**DAO code**

```
  public List<UserBean> list() throws SQLException {
        Connection con = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        List<UserBean> retbean = new ArrayList<UserBean>();
        try {
            con = dataSource.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select username from customer");
            rs = statement.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                rb.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
                retbean.add(rb);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return retbean;
    }

}
```

**Controller code**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "doLogin")
public ModelAndView doLogin(@ModelAttribute @Valid UserBean
                                    userBean, BindingResult result) {
    ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("login");
    if (!result.hasFieldErrors()) {
        if (!combatService.authenticateUser(userBean)) {
            result.addError(new ObjectError("err", "Invalid Credentials"));
        } else {
            if (retrieveService.list(userBean) != null) {
                view.setViewName("welcomes");
            }
        }
    }
    return view;
}
```

Actually If I login it will go to welcome page, To retrieve data from database to display in welcome page in angular js

Comment: Format your code!

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $http service of angularJs.

```
$http.get("/your_url").then(function(data){
    //do something with data here.
}, function(err){
});
```

And in your Controller add a mapping for url that returns data.

```
@RequestMapping("/your_url")
public @ResponseBody List<UserBean> list() throws SQLException{
    return myDao.list();
}
// By Convention you should not directly call DAO from controller use services and delegates
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. First you should access your DAO over controller. So you should write a new method inside controller which will talk to DAO and serve data to client side code (for you, angular) over JSON for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of Spring you are using you can do the following:

`@RestController` combines `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody` annotations. By using it you can omit the `@ResponseBody` annotations.

`@GetMapping` replaces `@RequestMapping(method = GET)`.

```
@RestController
public class SampleController {

    // autowire myDao object

    @GetMapping("/your_url")
    public ResponseEntity<List<UserBean>> list() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(myDao.list());
    }
}
```